# Crystal Reports with SQL-Server -- Using varchar with more than 8000 characters

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, varchar

Crystal Reports seems to misinterpret Varchar(max) as String(255).([see answer by codeulike here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141588/any-hidden-pitfalls-changing-a-column-from-varchar8000-to-varcharmax))

Is there any good way to get all of my data over to Crystal correctly?  I can't change the DB driver on Crystal, but I could modify the database.  Any solution has to not break anything (and if there's anything that might break, it probably will with ~130 stored procedures (many of which have hundreds of lines)).

Right now, we have separate views set up, but those use Varchar(8000).  I can't increase that number beyond 8000 (there is a finite limit, but it's about 10 times larger).  Same limit with Char.  I thought about Text, but I've been advised away from this before; my understanding is that it's sort of deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a text field in the db which will work in crystal.  But you will loose some of the ability to search in SQL Server.

Comment: This works.  We'll set up a separate table or view to store the data in.  Not quite what I was hoping for, but I guess this is the only bypass.

Comment: The other option we're considering is stored procedures that cast Varchar(max) to Text.  This will eliminate the extra table/view, which can be a hindrance with large data sets (tables need to be updated (overhead code) and views always run dynamically (too slow)).

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this in my report with `try_cast(<field> as text)` for Crystal Reports 2016 OEM.